# Mongoose not returning any documents after migrating database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I started working on this application on my local machine on a local database and it works fine here. I then cloned my project to an online server. I then used mongodump on my local database, uploaded my local db to the server, and used mongorestore to create a new database on the server with the same name as what I had on my local machine.

But now Mongoose in my application keeps returning zero results with no errors on all db queries. I used the mongo shell on my online server to test and see if the db was restored properly and it was, my documents do show up in the mongo shell on my online copy.

I am certain the db names are the same. The Mongoose model names are the same. The collection names are the same. I verified that everything on the server is exactly the same as I have it on my local copy, but for some reason Mongoose only finds my documents on my local db but not on the server.

Both my local db and the server db have authentication disabled, but are only listening on localhost, so the DB connection URI is also the same for both.

Comment: Could you please share the db URL. Because I think there may be problem with your db url.

Comment: @PankajJatav My db url is `mongodb://localhost/traderdb2` It is the same on the server and my local machine but it only works on my local machine.

Comment: Try by adding port in mongo URL. like mongodb://localhost:27017/traderdb2

Comment: First identify on which port you mongodb server is running.

Comment: @PankajJatav That's not the issue. I have a different webapp on the same URI only a different DB and that one works fine. It is running on the default port 27017. If the port was wrong then I would get an error when trying to connect to it, I'm not getting any errors, it connects to the db just fine.

Comment: Did you check manually that is there any data on you server in mongodb?

Comment: @PankajJatav Yes, using the mongo shell yields results in my traderdb2 database.

Comment: Did you try to insert any new document with you app.

Comment: @PankajJatav No, I don't have any sort of document insertion implemented in my app yet. Is there any special process to go through to migrate a mongodb that uses mongoose? Does mongoose keep an index of documents it tracks or something? Or does it require the database to be in any particular state? That's all I can think of.

Comment: You can insert some dummy data while app start. So you can ensure that you are connected to your valid database and it is allowing to communicated with app.

Comment: @PankajJatav Just did that, works perfectly and the dummy document shows up in mongo shell on the correct db.

Comment: Did you see the old and new document both in your mongo shell.

Comment: The old which you restore and the new dummy data which your app inserted??

Comment: @PankajJatav I see the dummy data the application inserted in the mongo shell, and I see the restored data in my mongo shell too. But the dummy document that the application inserted or any other data is not being returned by mongoose.

Comment: Dummy data inserted into same collection.

Comment: @PankajJatav Yes, I inserted a dummy document using my application with mongoose using a mongoose model, in a collection that already has documents in it that were restored from my local machine. Mongo shell sees all the documents just fine on the same database as my app. My application can write to the database using my mongoose models. But mongoose isn't returning any documents at all on a find query. But everything works fine on my local copy.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154379/discussion-between-pankaj-jatav-and-chrispytoes).